# Best way to look up currency units in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, currency

In my Ruby on Rails application I have this:

```
module Constants

  CURRENCIES = { 
    "EUR" => "&euro;",
    "USD" => "&dollar;",
    "GBP" => "&pound;"
  }

end
```

This works but is causing me some trouble because the HTML-entities can't be escaped in certain situations, e.g. when generating `.csv` or `.pdf` files.

It would be better to store the currency symbols like this:

```
module Constants

  CURRENCIES = { 
    "EUR" => "€",
    "USD" => "$",
    "GBP" => "£"
  }

end
```

However, when I do that I get this nasty error from Rails: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your logs and see which code is causing trouble.

Comment: `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` But why can't I use them here? I can use them in other places throughout the application without any problems.

Comment: Show us code that has a line with that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Just one line of code solving all my problems throughout the entire application.